# Why isn't my Express server reloading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm following along a tutorial, learning Express.

I wrote the following code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000);
```

Then when I ran the program in the console, and went to my browser (localhost:3000), I simply get the message: `Cannot GET /`

Which is to be expected of course.

Next, I'm instructed to update the code to this:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1>I Love Treehouse!</h1>");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("The frontend server is running on port 3000!");
});
```

If I kill the server and refresh the page however, I STILL get: `Cannot GET /'

And nothing is logged to the console.

I have killed the process, resaved the program, restarted my text editor and restarted my browser with no success.

Any idea what's happening? I'm following the tutorial line by line and can't see that I've missed anything.

Perhaps there is something out of date?

Thanks!

Comment: http://imgur.com/YulslpC — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using [nodemon](https://npmjs.com/package/nodemon)?

Comment: What command are you using to run the file?

Comment: Your first code example runs a server that doesn't have any routes configured so it doesn't do anything.  `Cannot GET /` would be expected.  Your second code example works just fine for responding to the `/` route in a normal environment.  I don't know why you refer to "kill the server".  If you kill the server, then there is no server and `Cannot GET /` would be the expected response.

Comment: Your second code example works just fine here.  Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Okay, I'm just ctrl C'ing , I thought that was the same

Comment: I've just gotten nodemon, not helping unfortunately!

My command is: `node app`

Comment: @jfriend00 `Cannot GET /` is a message from express not finding a route, not from the browser. if he shutdown the server he shouldn't be seing it.

Comment: there's not much we can do with this problem and info, though

Comment: @cviejo - Ridiculously confusing and unclear question.  It needs to be significantly clarified or closed.

Comment: agree, voted to close, sorry @MattCleary

Comment: How can I clarify further? What do I need to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with me... Try :

```
cd ../

## Create new folder
mkdir testfolder
cd testfolder

## Instal express
npm i express --save

## Create app.js and past your code
nano app.js

## Start app
node app.js
```

Comment: Dang, that worked. Thank you. Any idea what might have been wrong before on the original?

Comment: Really i don't know...

Comment: strange, thanks again